# One Change to JQuery Toggle Code: Content is showing before click. How do I make the content appear AFTER clicking the button in this code?

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
p { margin:-3px 0px 0px 3px;
background:#212121;
width:175px;
padding:10px;
color:#fff;
font-weight:500;
font-size:14px; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Toggle 'em</button>

<p>I figured out how to get the toggle to look and work up to this point, but I can't seem to get this content box to appear ONLY AFTER the button is clicked upon NOT before. And, when the visitor doesn't want to see the content anymore, s/he would have to click on the button (toggling). If you happen to know how to incorporate a delayed auto close on this toggle, please do tell (if not, no biggie--not my main focus). Thanks! </p>
    <script>
$("button").click(function () {
$("p").toggle("fast");
});    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know much about JQuery, but I used this site http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_toggle and figured out how to get the toggle to look and work up to this point, but I can't seem to get this content box to appear ONLY AFTER the button is clicked upon NOT before. And, when the visitor doesn't want to see the content anymore, s/he would have to click on the button (toggling). If you happen to know how to incorporate a delayed auto close on this toggle, please do tell (if not, no biggie--not my main focus). Thanks!

Comment: hey man see my answer, there is the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this instead!

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("p").hide();
$("button").click(function () {
$("p").toggle("fast");
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6NJR/

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

> display:none;

to the CSS

Comment: Oh! I saw the answer above yours first and tried it. Anyway, thanks a mil for responding so fast.

Comment: Well it would be a better practice to use CSS instead of Javascript if possible.